# How do I prevent R function "step" from outputing to the console?

Tags: r

The step function always prints the result of each stepwise regression to the console, even if the executed statement is an assignment, not evaluation. How do I make it just silently select predictors, without printing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the help file of function `step()` you can find that there is argument `trace=`. If you set this argument to `0` then only final predictors are printed or if you use `step()` in assignment then nothing is printed.

Modified example from help file:

```
summary(lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss))
slm1 <- step(lm1,trace=0)
summary(slm1)
```

Or

```
step(lm1, trace=0)

Call:
lm(formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)       Agriculture         Education          Catholic  
         62.1013           -0.1546           -0.9803            0.1247  
Infant.Mortality  
          1.0784
```